# How to search custom post types with custom taxonomies and custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to create a custom search for properties(custom post type) in wordpress. Category(Sale and To-Let) and Location(Dublin 1,Dublin 4,etc) are taxonomy(custom taxonomy) and price(10000,etc) is populated through a function which I match(less than or equal) to the custom field(acf) price so I have to create a query which is includes taxonomies and custom fields. The other two custom fields(acf) are display and status(if they are Sold they should not be in the search). When submit is clicked it does pass the correct values and I var_dumped the values when on listings-results page and they are correct. There is something wrong in my query to WP as it will display all the results.

It should search as per the values selected in the select field but it is displaying all results. For Eg: if Sale is selected then only results for Sale should be displayed but it displayed all 15 properties.

Please help I am a newbie in PHP and WP. Please find the link for my code. http://pastebin.com/9qKgjMnM

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not certain this will be the answer to your issue, I did notice that in your code the taxonomy name (Lines 63 and 70) contained spaces. I'm not sure how you registered the taxonomies, the guidelines specified by Wordpress here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy state that the taxonomy name should not contain any spaces - *"Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character"*. So, just make sure you are referencing the correct taxonomy name in your code

EDIT* The issue at hand here was in the taxonomy query. When using slug in taxonomy queries you should compare against arrays, like so

```
array(
   'taxonomy' => 'location',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms'    => array($_GET['location']),
   'operator' => 'IN'
)
```

Comment: I realised that when I was reading but I check in mysql and it is property category but when I used get_terms() on another page with property category it works and gives the correct information, I will change it and check as well. Thank You.

Comment: Its still the same :(

Comment: Ok, well while I can't offer any concrete help here, what I would do considering there are so many variables in the query is to break your query down parameter by parameter to see which is bringing back results correctly and which is not. That should help you to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: I did that and price works well and filters and shows the results as per selected value but the taxonomies category and location is not working. So I think issue is with taxonomy, it is not comparing with the variables though i did a var_dump and category and location are getting passed through GET.

Comment: Ok, well then it could be the operator and terms section of your query. changing the operator to 'IN' and change your terms value to array($prop_slug) in the tax query section

Comment: Andrew, I owe you big time. I tried IN and tried array but always with some other options and not IN and array together and trying so many options I missed out on that option. I want to mark this as an answer please edit your answer so I can mark it or do I mark it anyways. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help out. Those taxonomy queries are very powerful but sometimes need a bit of tweaking to get working. Do I need to make a change to my answer for it to be marked correct?

Comment: Yeah, i requested so that i can mark the answer where it shows IN and array and not space in taxonomy. I marked it anyways. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem - I've updated the answer to help others with the same issue.